How to import in Python the library spark_session?
I am trying to run a ipynb where there are these libraries:

from spark_session import get_spark_session
from blob_settings import BLOB_STORAGE

Does anyone know how to import them?
many thanks!
Of course I tryed with "pip install spark_session" but it doesn't work.
Tried to import pyspark, pyspark-types but the error remains.
The error in the ipynb is this one:
---> 11 from spark_session import get_spark_session
     12 from blob_settings import BLOB_STORAGE

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spark_session'

Obviously I looked into Google but haven't find anything about how to import "spark_session". Sometimes you have to call the pip command with a different name, but I can't find this name.
If nobody knows this, I should conclude this is a library wrote by the author of this ipynb but not shared with me.

Please edit the question and add the output of this command pip show spark_session and also the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)
